# ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "server API URL": 443 failed to respond; nested exception is NoHttpResponseException

Tags: spring-boot, http, httpclient, resttemplate

I am getting `ResourceAccessException: I/O error (server failed to respond), while trying to call a server API through RestTemplate`. This is happening frequently but with postman every time it is working fine.

My RestTemplate configuration:

```
@Bean
public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager result = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    result.setMaxTotal(3000);
    result.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(3000);
    result.setValidateAfterInactivity(10000);
    return result;
}
```

```
@Bean
public RequestConfig requestConfig() {
    return RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(60000)
            .setConnectTimeout(60000)
            .setSocketTimeout(60000)
            .build();
}
```

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager, RequestConfig requestConfig) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    return HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
            .build();
}
```

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(HttpClient httpClient) {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Can anyone please help me here? am I missing any configuration for RestTemplate to resolve this issue or any other solution I can resolve this?

PLEASE HELP!

Trying to  make a POST request with RestTemplate using

`restTemplate.postForEntity()`, getting `ResourceAccessException: I/O error (server address.com:443  failed to respond) nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException`